# Newly installed package for react changing the node modules

Tags: reactjs, npm, node-modules

I am completing a project and I am very new to React.

I tried to install a new package named [react-toastify](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-toastify) and suddenly the project that I am creating which is almost done is showing me this error:

```
 ./node_modules/react/index.js
 Module build failed: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 
 '/Users/mynamehere/react/projectnamehere/frontend/node_modules/react/index.js'
```

When I checked on the directory mentioned, the file indeed was not there. But this is working since I was working on this project for a long while.

I tried to re-install everything using `npm install` but to no avail.

This is the initial log that I picked up from `.npm/_logs` on the first occurrence of error.

```
 0 info it worked if it ends with ok
 1 verbose cli [ '/usr/local/bin/node', '/usr/local/bin/npm', 'start' ]
 2 info using npm@5.0.0
 3 info using node@v8.0.0
 4 verbose run-script [ 'prestart', 'start', 'poststart' ]
 5 info lifecycle frontend@0.1.0~prestart: frontend@0.1.0
 6 silly lifecycle frontend@0.1.0~prestart: no script for prestart, continuing
 7 info lifecycle frontend@0.1.0~start: frontend@0.1.0
 8 verbose lifecycle frontend@0.1.0~start: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
 9 verbose lifecycle frontend@0.1.0~start: PATH: /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/bin/node-gyp-bin:/Users/edper/react/readable-redux/frontend/node_modules/.bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/X11/bin:/usr/local/share/dotnet:/usr/local/go/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/Current/Commands
 10 verbose lifecycle frontend@0.1.0~start: CWD: /Users/edper/react/readable-redux/frontend
 11 silly lifecycle frontend@0.1.0~start: Args: [ '-c', 'react-scripts start' ]
 12 error cb() never called!
 13 error This is an error with npm itself. Please report this error at:
 14 error <https://github.com/npm/npm/issues>
```

I tried deleting the `node_modules` directory as per suggestion below but I get the same error that I had the last time, as shown below:

```
npm ERR! file sh
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall spawn
npm ERR! frontend@0.1.0 start: `react-scripts start`
npm ERR! spawn ENOENT
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the frontend@0.1.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
```

Comment: Try deleting the node_modules folder and then run `npm install`

Comment: I am trying as you suggested but I got the same error that I got the last time.

Comment: delete all node modules. hit npm outdated. check what all dependencies have changed. update package json and hit npm install. beware there might be breaking changes in the new node modules so you need to check the changelog of all updated modules

Comment: @hannadrehman Could it be that it breaks because I am using an older node on this one earlier, I think around v7 and just yesterday, I installed v8 node? But everything was working until I installed `react-toastify` package. I am not familiar `node` also and I don't know if I could do it as you suggested if something breaks again.

Comment: yes it possible, because every major release will have breaking changes, many features becomes unsupported as node is evolving very quickly. thats why you should update the node modules also.. when you hit ```npm outdated``` you will get the release info also. before updating check the release notes and support etc. @Edper

Comment: This is what I got when I run `npm oudated`    Package           Current  Wanted  Latest  Location  
react-helmet      MISSING   5.2.0   5.2.0  frontend  
react-router-dom  MISSING   4.2.2   4.2.2  frontend  
react-scripts     MISSING  1.0.17  1.0.17  frontend  
react-wysiwyg     MISSING   2.2.1   2.2.1  frontend  
redux             MISSING   3.7.2   3.7.2  frontend  
redux-thunk       MISSING   2.2.0   2.2.0  frontend  
sort-by           MISSING   1.2.0   1.2.0  frontend

Comment: @hannadrehman: Thanks it works now! It is a case of outdated packages. GOD bless you sir!

Comment: happy to help sir @Edper. i am posting it as the answer so that others might also get help with the same issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible that when you updated your Node version some the features might have gotten deprecated. whenever there is a major node release you should always try to update all the node modules with it.
to check the outdated node modules you can use  `npm outdated`

To fix this problem you can delete all the node modules.

hit `npm outdated`

update your package.json with all the latest module versions available.

and hit `npm install`

but be sure to check the module changelogs and see what all has been changed.
if there are breaking changes, it might affect the working of your application also.

Comment: Thank you for your help once again!